# Jhipster - Modify existing MongoDB entity

Tags: json, mongodb, jhipster

I have an entity generated with JHipster.

**myFile.json**

```
{
"fluentMethods": true,
"relationships": [],
"fields": [
    {
        "fieldName": "fileName",
        "fieldType": "String"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "file",
        "fieldType": "byte[]",
        "fieldTypeBlobContent": "any",
        "fieldValidateRules": [
            "required"
        ]
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "size",
        "fieldType": "String"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "dateCreated",
        "fieldType": "ZonedDateTime",
        "fieldValidateRules": []
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "dateModified",
        "fieldType": "ZonedDateTime"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "createdBy",
        "fieldType": "String"
    }
],
"dto": "mapstruct",
"service": "serviceClass",
"entityTableName": "my_file",
"jpaMetamodelFiltering": false,
"pagination": "pagination"
```

}

At this point I would like to add some fields. I want to add an **Option** field which would be Object[] type with name and desc fields. Is this the right way to do this?? Im thinking adding this code at the end of the fields..

```
    ...
    {
        "fieldName": "myFileOption",
        "fieldType": "Obejct[]",
        "fields" : [{
            "fieldName" : "name",
            "fieldType" : "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldName" : "desc",
            "fieldType" : "String"
        }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking... You have a myriad of tags that also don't shed light... are you asking how to use jhipster, spring, angular, or how to edit json?

Comment: @Jeff I want to edit the json file to update my entity with the option object inserted. Youre right about tags

Comment: You'll have to forgive my ignorance on jhipster, but if all you want to do is add fields to a Json file, then just add the fields. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You add entites with the entity generator, and then you can edit the json, and `--regenerate`

```
jhipster entity --skip-client Option
```

this is presuming that you want to add a now entity called `Option`.